# Properties of the greatest common divisor: $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a, b-a)$ and $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a, b \text{ mod } a)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Prove that
>
> (a) gcd(a, b) = gcd (a, b – a)
>
> (b) Let r be the remainder if we divide b by a. Then gcd(a, b) = gcd(a, r).

I solved part a like:

Assume a=pcommon*pa b=pcommon*pb

gcd (a,b) = pcommon

b-a = pcommon*(pb-pa)  So:

gcd(a, b-a) = common again

But I need help for part b guys I can solve it but I need a mathematical expression.

Comment: $r = b-qa$ for some integer $q$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $d$ divides $a$ and $b$ then $a=da'$, $b=db'$. Therefore, $a-b=d(a'-b')$, so $d$ divides $a-b$. We have proved that every common divisor of $a$ and $b$ divides $a$ (of course) and $a-b$. Thus, $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $a$ and $a-b$ and therefore, $\gcd(a,b)\le\gcd(a,a-b)$.

But then $\gcd(a-b,a)$ divides $a$ and $a-(a-b)=b$, so $\gcd(a-b,a)\le\gcd(a,b)$. Tehn, they are equal.

The second part is very similar. Just remember that $b=aq+r$.